# Javascript event not bubbling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the markup below:[image]

And I have some jQuery I just added to toggle the row color:
[image]

Clicking anywhere in the row switches the view, as below:

[image]

The problem is that since I added the toggle function the links don't work.  The toggle handler seems to capture the event.  I would expect the link to get the event first and then the row, so the link should work fine.

Does anyone see the problem?

Thanks

Comment: `toggle()` is deprecated. It is not recommended to use it anymore.

Comment: @VisioN it must be deprecated because `toogle()` never existed. Did you mean `toggle()`? :)

Comment: Please when adding code, add actual code that people can test not images of code.

Comment: *NB:* Please, don't include your code as images. Sometimes we need to reproduce your case fast, not retyping everything.

Comment: @mattytommo My fingers thought I was typing `google` :D

Comment: @VisioN Hahahaha I love that, the hands type one thing, the brain thinks another = a mixture of the two :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that toggle() is not what you use it for.

Check: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

It makes the matched element hide and show according to it's current state.

What you might want to use is [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) based on your example.

Also it's not clear from your question that what is the purpose of your javascript. When (on what event) you want to change an item's color? On clicking it?

You are clearly misusing the toggle() function, but I'm not sure when and what do you want to happen.

EDIT: I see you were aiming for the [toggle event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) which is deprecated.

EDIT2: I have made you a jsfiddle which I think does what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/kytJ3/1/

The html:

```
<div id="test" class="test-class">DURP<br />HURP<br />
    <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">A LINK</a>
</div>
```

The js:

```
$('#test').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('test-class');
});
```

The css:

```
div {
    color: red;
}
.test-class {
    color: blue;
}
```

This also results in cleaner (style free) javascript. And the link works fine.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I should have been using toggleClass(). toggle(handler1,handler2) is deprecated and was removed from jQuery in 1.9. Thanks.  I have it working now.